# Android connect with Google cloud sql

Tags: android, google-cloud-sql

Can anyone let me know where I can find any documentation or tutorial on How to connect Google Cloud Sql from Android. I managed to connect Google Cloud Sql from Google app engine. Need advice on how i can connect Google cloud Sql from Android. Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we can't connect any other external application with Google Cloud SQL. This can be only with Google App Engine Apps